# Setup a VPN Server on Debian that Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6 can handle natively?

Tags: debian, vpn, server-administration

does someone know a VPN Server for Debian whose connections can be handles by Mac OS X and Windows 7 natively?

I have found several vpn solutions on the net, but all either need some software to be installed or I could not find information about it.

Thanks,
Heinrich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the PPTP protocol. They are both handled well under both Windows and Mac OSX.

To implement that under debian, you can use the PPTPD daemon. Another option would be to use an appliance like "pfsense", and get that virtualized on your Debian server.

Good luck!